# How to let a TextView overlap over an ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RelativeLayout and want to that my textfield will overlap over the given ImageButton. Currently the textfield is behind the imagebutton. I tried several options but did not find the correct one, any idea?

Thanks

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/qrCode_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/qrCode_hint"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_start_barcode"
    android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_start_barcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/select_form"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:onClick="startBarcodeAction"
    android:src="@drawable/barcode_bg" />
```

Comment: Set the TextView AFTER the ImageButton. So, it will be "closer to you" on the imaginary Z-Axis (stacked over the ImageButton)

Answer (score 0):

The `RelativeLayout` sets the Z-Index based on ordering of children.
So when you add a view below the others it will set Z-Index of that child higher than the last child.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and put in the following order:

1. ImageButton
2. TextView

This will ensure that the TextView will be on top of the ImageButton.